# NSInvalidArgumentException Invalid type in JSON write DemographicsPojo

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am getting a **NSInvalidArgumentException** when I try to run the following `JSONSerialization` using `Alamofire` on `swift 3` code.

> try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postData, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

On debug, `postData` is returning the value below.

```
key __NSCFString *  "demographicsPojo"  0x000060800005e8a0
value   _TtC7MyApp16DemographicsPojo *  0x6080001c5cd0  0x00006080001c5cd0
[0] _TtC7MyApp16DemographicsPojo    
createdTimeMilliSecs    Int64?  1487253369999
dateOfBirthMilliSecs    Int64?  1487253369999
demographicsRoleType    Int?    3
gender  Int?    0
isDemographicsActive    Int?    3
isRecordActive  Int?    0
isTermsAndConditionsAccepted    Int?    3
licenseExpiryDate   Int64?  1487253369999
mobilePhone String? "9876543210"    some
termsAndConditionsAcceptedTime  Int64?  1487253369999
termsAndConditionsText  String? ""  some
updatedTimeMilliSecs    Int64?  1487253369999
```

I am new to `Swift 3`. I used my Android based JSON files to reverse engineer the `DemographicsPojo` to swift. I wonder if I need to avoid using `Optionals` completely in the Pojo's ? Is that the issue ?

Comment: Don't use `try!` carelessly. Use a `do-catch` block to catch a possible error. Set also the exception breakpoint to get detailed information about the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Swift would not serialize arbitrary object into JSON string. You can check this with a call to `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject`.

You need to convert your object into a dictionary first. Or use third-party JSON serializer library, like [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss)