# How to convert this to a POST call with a JSON serialized Object

Tags: swift, swift3, http-post

I have tried Alamofire, I have tried it with all my heart. It just does not work for me. I finally got http GET working, but I need to get http POST working. Our POST API's take a Request object that has all the necessary data in it. I have requested the backend developers to provide me with a KEY-VALUE pair JSON (no embedded objects/arrays) so that I can use a Dictionary in my swift code convert that to json and send the request. All I need is now to convert the below code to POST.

My earlier questions that did not help much.
[NSInvalidArgumentException Invalid type in JSON write DemographicsPojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276134/nsinvalidargumentexception-invalid-type-in-json-write-demographicspojo)

[Swift 3.0, Alamofire 4.0 Extra argument 'method' in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113651/swift-3-0-alamofire-4-0-extra-argument-method-in-call)

I have given up on Alamofire. I want to use Foundation classes. Simple basic and fundamental way of life :).

```
 func callWebService(url : String) {
        // Show MBProgressHUD Here
        var config                              :URLSessionConfiguration!
        var urlSession                          :URLSession!

        config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config)

        // MARK:- HeaderField
        let HTTPHeaderField_ContentType         = "Content-Type"

        // MARK:- ContentType
        let ContentType_ApplicationJson         = "application/json"

        //MARK: HTTPMethod
        let HTTPMethod_Get                      = "GET"

        let callURL = URL.init(string: url)

        var request = URLRequest.init(url: callURL!)

        request.timeoutInterval = 60.0 // TimeoutInterval in Second
        request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.addValue(ContentType_ApplicationJson, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField_ContentType)
        request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod_Get

        let dataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error **")

                return
            }
            do {
                let resultJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                print("Result",resultJson!)
            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
        print("..In Background..")
    }
```

Comment: I am a bit confused you asking to rewrite code to send POST request? Please try it by your self, and than if it is not working ask for help.

Comment: Trust me when I say this, I have tried it and failed. I finally have a working GET, but cant get POST working.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass JSON string and the API URL to this function. Complete code for POST.

```
func POST(api:String,jsonString:String,completionHandler:@escaping (_ success:Bool,_ response:String?,_ httpResponseStatusCode:Int?) -> Void)  {

    let url = URL(string: api)

    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    request.timeoutInterval = 60.0

    //additional headers
    if let token = Helper.readAccessToken() {
        request.setValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }

    let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        var responseCode = 0
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            responseCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            print("responseCode \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }

        if error != nil {
            completionHandler(false, error?.localizedDescription,nil)

        } else {
            let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
            completionHandler(true, responseString, responseCode)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```